# Filter Design in Matlab

Tags: matlab, filters, signal-analysis

I want to design a filter to remove all frequency components from a *.wav* file except those within $\pm 25\,\text{Hz}$ of $523\,\text{Hz}$ as well as its harmonics (up to the Nyquist frequency).

**Attempt**

I tried to suppress frequencies below 523-25 Hz using a high-pass filter, and suppress the ones higher than 523+25 Hz using a low pass filter. Here's my code:

```
[s, Fs] = wavread('x.wav');

for N=2:1:(Fs/(2*(523+25)))
    % High-pass filter
    FsNorm =  (523-25).*N / (Fs/2);
    [b,a] = butter(10, FsNorm, 'high');
    sHigh = filtfilt(b, a, s);

    % Low pass
    FsNorm = (523+25).*N / (Fs/2);
    [b,a] = butter(10, FsNorm, 'low'); 
    sLow = filtfilt(b, a, s);
end

wavwrite(sLow, Fs, 'x_filtered');
```

The code doesn't work, the resulting file is mute. My intention is to apply each filter to the output of the previous filter, but I don't know how to implement this in code.

I used $(523+25) N_{max} < \frac{F_s}{2}$ to include all the harmonics up to the Nyquist frequency.

So what do I need to do to get this filter to work?

**Edit:**

```
Here's my new code:

[s, Fs] = wavread('x.wav');

sNew = zeros(size(s));

for N=2:1:(Fs/(2*(523+25)))
    % High-pass filter
    FsNorm =  (523-25).*N / (Fs/2);
    [b,a] = butter(10, FsNorm, 'high');
    sHigh = filter(b, a, s);

    % Low pass
    FsNorm = (523+25).*N / (Fs/2);
    [b,a] = butter(10, FsNorm, 'low'); 
    sLow = filter(b, a, s);

    Now sum the results
    sNew = sHigh + sLow;
end

sNew

wavplay(sNew,Fs);
wavwrite(sNew, Fs, 'x_filtered');
```

I still get `sNew=0` and the sound is still mute. What's wrong?

Comment: Any particular reason to use `filtfilt` instead of `filter`?

Comment: There is no particular reason. In fact, I am not sure if `filtfilt` is even the correct call to use in this case.

Comment: As a general rule, you shouldn't use `filtfilt` unless you know exactly why you need it.

Comment: This question is very close to a programming question. I believe a significant problem is identified by the first part of `user20703`'s answer.  But the second part of that answer is, I believe, incorrect. `keith`'s answer seems to be the way to go.

Comment: @Merin @Merin :  your line `s = sNew;` will zero out your input signal. Why is that there?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to make a simple modification:

Send the original signal through each filter and sum the output of each filter together to get your final result.

At the moment you are passing the filtered data on to each subsequent filter. If you think carefully about that, the output will be silent i.e. you filter out everything but 523 Hz  +/- 25 which leaves you just frequencies around 523 Hz, then you take that and filter out everything but 1046 Hz  +/- 25 which will strip out the frequencies around 523 Hz and then you have silence after just two iterations of your loop.

---

```
s = s(:).';
sNew = zeros(1,length(s)); % The eventual output

for N=2:1:(Fs/(2*(523+25)))
    % High-pass filter
    FsNorm =  (523-25).*N / (Fs/2);
    [b,a] = butter(10, FsNorm, 'high');
    sHigh = filter(b, a, s);

    % Low pass
    FsNorm = (523+25).*N / (Fs/2);
    [b,a] = butter(10, FsNorm, 'low'); 
    sLow = filter(b, a, sHigh); % Note we are filtering sHigh, not 's'

    % Now sum the results
    sNew = sNew + sLow;
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this explanation. But do you know what would be the code that can sum all the filter outputs together to form the final output?

Comment: @Merin There's an operator called `+`… It even works on vectors…

Comment: Thank you so much but I am still getting an error when I try to run this code. The error is in the first line `sNew = zeros(s)`. It says: `Error using zeros; Size vector must be a row vector with real elements`. Furthermore, is it not better to use the `filter` function instead of `filtfilt`? (since we intend our final design to be applied continuously)

Comment: @MarcusMüller I have used this code by keith, and  I changed the first line to `sNew = zeros(size(s));`. So why is the code still not working? I get `sNew=0` and the resulting sound is mute.

Comment: @Merin :  your line `s = sNew;` will zero out your input signal. Why is that there?

Comment: @PeterK. That was suggested by user20703. I have now removed the line `s = sNew;` (I edited my post). But Matlab still returns all zeros. Why is that?

Comment: @Merin : Why are you filtering `sNew`. It is zero. You just set it to zero.  Only filter `s`.

Comment: @PeterK. I see. I changed it to `s`. But now instead of zeros, all values in the output are equal to `NaN`. What does that mean?

Comment: @Merin It means your filters are poorly designed and are generating filter coefficients with nulls.

Comment: @PeterK. Do you know how one could improve the design of the filters to avoid the nulls? Is that related to the order of the filter used or something else?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38913/discussion-between-peter-k-and-merin).

Answer (score 0):

You code currently produces a signal `sLow` that is `s` through a single low-pass filter (using the last value of `N`), because you keep applying all the filtering to the original signal `s`.

So you probably need to substitute `s` with `sNew` in the loop. Before the loop starts do `s = sNew`. At the end of each loop do `sNew = sLow + sHigh`. Then `sNew` is your final result.

Comment: I made all the changes you've mentioned to my code, I have added my new code to my original post. So, why do I still get `sNew = 0`? The resulting .wav file is still mute. What is wrong with the code?